# Android release app at specific date and time

Tags: android, release

Is there a way to release an Android app at a specific date and time. A client wants the app to be released tomorrow at noon (I want to submit it now and tell the developer console that it should be released tomorrow at noon). I've never seen this before on the developer console, so I'm wondering if this is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it usually takes half hour minimum for your build to go live on app store after you upload make sure you upload build say one or two hour before noon.

Comment: @apk I know, but I was curious if there was a way to do this. If I want to release an app in the weekend, I can just set date and time and the developer console will do the rest. Thought maybe somebody knew this

Comment: No option to do so. Why you want do it is it lucky if you upload on that time . :)

Comment: Jenkins  should handle thst

Comment: @RobertRowntree How do I use Jenkins and what is it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507958/how-to-upload-an-apk-from-jenkins-hudson-to-play-store

Comment: @RobertRowntree thanks for the link, but it says any apks uploaded will be published immediately and it doesn't work on new apps. I'll just stick with releasing it manually

Comment: @RobertRowntree thanks for your help, but I'll just release it manually. I was hoping for a way to do it from the Developer Console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are now able to do "timed publishing" in the Google Play Store when submitting updates and when "releasing a new APK" (which apparently is not the same as publishing your app for the first time). I think you are able to do timed publishing when first releasing your app to alpha/beta users, though I have not personally tried it.

Head to [this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469) and read under the heading "Update apps using standard or timed publishing" for details.

Basically, you need to login to the Google Play Developer Dashboard, choose the application entry, and look towards the top right for an easy to miss drop-down called 'Standard publishing'. Click that and choose 'Turn on timed publishing...' to see more information before accepting the change.

*Edit: I have recently tried using Timed Publishing when pushing out the first version of a new app and it actually did delay the app launch until I hit the Go Live button. Though Google's own documentation seems to imply that the first version of your app cannot use Timed Publishing to be aware that it may not work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, 'timed publishing' doesn't do what you'd think it does. It only gives the developer control for an update to actually go live by giving a 'Go Live' button. [More info](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282)

Comment: @TimKist Yea that is how I have experienced timed publishing as well. Timed publishing does not give you a date picker to choose from, you still have to manually click the button when you want it released.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is available for Play Store. iOS App Store I have seen this feature but never in lay store.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm asking.